# Why would 'string' become an ineligible variable if I comment out Newline

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

Complete newbie here and I had a quick question with regards to **newline** in my code. So I understand that inserting the `using namespace std` is bad practice and in writing my program I avoided using `cout` and `cin` without the adding the `std::` portion first. But I figured since I'm not importing the **namespace** library I could just comment it out. But when I did this my `string` name for the variables became unrecognized (red lines underneath it). The red lines disappear when I allow **namespace** to be imported again. Is the variable `string` only available in the **namespace** library?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
//using namespace std;



// read and compare names
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter two names \n";
    string first;
    string second;
    std:: cin >> first >> second; // read two strings
    if (first == second) std::cout << "that's the same name twice! \n";
    if (first < second) std::cout << first << " is alphabetically before " 
<< second << '\n';
    if (first > second) std::cout << first << " is alphabetically after " << 
second << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't include  `using namespace std` then you will need to say

```
std::string first;
std::string second;
```

because `string` is defined in the `standard` namespace also (as well as `cout` etc).

So yes you are right that `string` is only defined in `standard`. `string` is an object (not a primitive type) and it is this that allows you to do the `if(first==second)` comparison. Otherwise the "normal" way to compare string is using `strcmp()` or similar.